# Laravel eloquent relationship chaining

Tags: php, laravel-5, psql

I have three table shares, share_users, users structure as follows -

```
users ( Table ) -
     -id
     -name
     -email

shares( Table ) -
     -id
     -name

share_users - 
     -id
     -user_id
     -share_id
```

I want to retrieve user data from share model using Laravel eloquent relations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just define a many-to-many relation from the Share model to the User model..?

Answer (score 1):

If you define the many to many relationship to the User model in the Share model correctly, as described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships, you will be able to retrieve the users for a share easily.

add to Share model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class, 'share_users');
}
```

Consumption:

```
$share = Share::find(1);

foreach($share->users as $user) {
 dump($user);
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "share_user" does not exist LINE 1: ...er_id" as "pivot_user_id" from "users" inner join "share_use... ^ (SQL: select "users".*, "share_user"."share_id" as "pivot_share_id", "share_user"."user_id" as "pivot_user_id" from "users" inner join "share_user" on "users"."id" = "share_user"."user_id" where "share_user"."share_id" = 1)

Comment: Laravel's default for pivot table is singular names in alphabetical order. e.g. share_user. It looks like you have plural users - share_users. You could fix this by renaming the table, or by overriding the default when defining the relationship, which is the second parameter on belongsToMany(), as described on the eloquent-relationships page linked to in my answer. I've updated my answer with this change. Does this resolve the error?

Comment: Yess this is working, Thank you so much. I'm really thankful. :-)

Comment: Glad I could help!